# php error in Vanguard (the Laravel component?)

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have just tried to install Vanguard (vanguardapp.io) but when I try to launch the installer I run into a 500 server error. I have given 777 rights on the storage folder and all its subfolders and files as was stated in the manual. When I look closely at the error I see:

> 13.03.2018 10:35:48 test01 [client 51.0.0.0] #0 /mnt/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('view')
>
> 13.03.2018 10:35:48 test01 [client 51.0.0.0] #1 /mnt/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')
>
> 13.03.2018 10:35:48 test01 [client 51.0.0.0] #2 /mnt/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array)
>
> 13.03.2018 10:35:48 test01 [client 51.0.0.0] #3 /mnt/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(721): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array)
>
> 13.03.2018 10:35:48 test01 [client 51.0.0.0] #4 /mnt/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('view', Array)
>
> 13.03.2018 10:35:48 test01 [client 51.0.0.0] #5 /mnt/htdocs/t in /mnt/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 752

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: That's only the stacktrace. Can you attach the erorr message itself to your question?

Comment: This is the error, I'm not getting anything else.
When visiting the website I just get a 500 Internal server error.

Comment: Are you sure that there is only a stack trace given and not an error?

Comment: Well, i use Strato as webhoster and they have an error.log file in their backend which I use to see the errors my pages generate. Don't know how else to see errors?